# Error no route to host using expect while reading host user name and passwords from a csv file

Tags: expect

I writing a script to read user name, password and host info from a file. 
I then parse this info to get the variables.  I would then like to add these variables to an expect script that reads all the ip address in my file and performs certain commands on the remote devices that I am trying to log into.  The script works when it connects to a known host however What I am seeing is that there is one device that is not up and running and the system promps with the following error. 
ssh: connect to host 192.168.3.2 port 22: No route to host

the file 
I would like to do 2 things 
1. Skip the host and move to the next host
2. log the host that is down to another file so that I can troubleshoot the network issue to that host.

Please see the script below.  Please any help is greatly accepted.

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f



## Read the file
set fid [open /csv_pars/employee1.csv]
set content [read $fid]
close $fid

## Split into records on newlines
set records [split $content "\n"]

## Iterate over the records
foreach rec $records {

## Split into fields on comma
set fields [split $rec ","]
## Assign fields to variables and print some out...
lassign $fields\  ipaddr username password
puts "$ipaddr"
puts "$username"
puts "$password"





if {$ipaddr == ""} continue
spawn ssh  -X "$username@$ipaddr"
sleep 2
expect "password:"


sleep 2
send  "$pass\r"
expect  "$"
send -- "ls -l\r"
expect "$"
send -- "exit\r"


expect eof




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expect to see one of two things: the password prompt, or the error message:

```
spawn ssh  -X "$username@$ipaddr"
expect {
    -re "password: ?$" {
        send  "$pass\r"
        expect  "$"
        send -- "ls -l\r"
        expect "$"
        send -- "exit\r"
        expect eof
    }
    "No route to host" {
        set fid [open error.log a]
        puts $fid "[clock format [clock seconds]]: No route to host $ipaddr"
        close $fid
    }
}
```

Comment: Glen I am having one problem when I set the error log I am not sure where it logs.  I searched the server and could not find the log. Does this mean that I have to build a log file first.